# Solving $ T ( n ) = 8 T \left( \left\lfloor \frac n 2 \right\rfloor \right) + 1 $ using Akra-Bazzi

Tags: asymptotics, analysis-of-algorithms

I was trying to apply Akra-Bazzi to solve
$$ T ( n ) = 8 T \left( \left\lfloor \frac n 2 \right\rfloor \right) + 1 $$
but I was having some issues.

I was told that the correct way to solve it to express the floor in the form (for the special case of $ k = 1 $):
$$ b n + h ( n ) $$
and they gave me:
$$ \frac n 2 + \left\lfloor \frac n 2 \right\rfloor - \frac n 2 $$
where
$$ h ( n ) = \left\lfloor \frac n 2 \right\rfloor - \frac n 2 $$
and from that get the appropriate value of $ p $ for the integral. However, I was wondering, why would the following not be a correct way of expressing that:
$$ \frac n 8 + \left\lfloor \frac n 2 \right\rfloor - \frac n 8 $$
It for sure is the same thing than the floor of $ n $ over $ 2 $, but why would using that be wrong? Wouldn't that affect the value of $ p $ and thus the value of the integral and thus lead to a different solution?

My hunch is that $ h ( n ) $ probably does not satisfy the following anymore:
$$ h ( n ) = O \left( \frac n { \log ^ 2 n } \right) \text , $$
and that's the reason you can't do it, but how do I show that rigorously (by the way, it's obviously clear to me that the first one I suggested satisfies that bound because it's bounded from above by $ 1 $. However, it's not clear to me that the second suggestion is wrong).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$h(n) = \left\lfloor \frac{n}{2}\right\rfloor - \frac{n}{8}\sim\frac{3n}8\notin O\left(\frac{n}{\log^2n}\right)$$

Comment: thats what I suspected! However, I didn't know how to verify that rigorously. Sorry if its really obvious to you, but do you mind providing more details?

Comment: Which one? The equivalence part or the $\notin$ part?

Comment: the $\frac{3n}{8}$, if its $3n/8$. I guess the equivalence part

Comment: For every $x$, $x-1\lt\lfloor x\rfloor\leqslant x$ hence $(3n/8)-1\lt h(n)\leqslant3n/8$, which is more than enough.